# How to insert my messages as input in my feature columns in SVM estimator in the Tensorflow package

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, svm, text-classification

I am trying to implement my text classification model which classifies messages as spam or not in Tensorflow using SVM Model. 
I have only 2 features rn that is a contact name and message, do I need to convert them into numbers or can it be directly used as input in feature column

```
svm = tf.contrib.learn.SVM(
    example_id_column=example_id_column_name,
    feature_columns=(tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(
        column_name=x_column_name, dimension=90),),
    l2_regularization=0.1)

svm.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it give an error? If it gives an error something like this: "cannot convert string to float", then you cannot use it. If it works, then you can use it.

In the documentation it is also explained what you need:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/SVM